# Problema con la conexion en php

Tags: php, insert, conexión

Esta es mi clase persona, el problema que tengo es que me aparece error en el
**$this->dbConn->** prepare($sql);

El error que me aparece es este:  **Expected type 'object'. Found 'string'.**

Intenté solucionarlo pero no tuve éxito.
Agradezco si pueden ayudarme

```
<?php
require_once 'Conexion.php';
class Persona extends Conexion
{
    private $IdPersona;
    private $Nombre;
    private $Correo;
    private $Clave;
    private $dbConn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $conn = new Conexion();
        $this->dbConn = $conn->conectar();
    }

    public function insertar(string $nombre, string $correo, string $clave)
    {
        $this->Nombre = $nombre;
        $this->Correo = $correo;
        $this->Clave = $clave;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, correo, clave) VALUES(:nombre, :correo, :clave)";
        $stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nombre", $this->Nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":correo", $this->Correo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(":clave",  $this->Clave, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Persona();
$insertar = $obj->insertar("admin", "admin@gmail.com", "admin");
```

Comment: Es posible que el problema esté en Conexion.php ya que está devolviendo un String cuando lo estás usando como objeto `$this->dbConn`

Comment: Independientemente del error deberías reflexionar: ¿qué tienen en común una Persona y una Conexión?

Comment: Al margen de la pregunta... me llama la atención que muchas de tus preguntas tienen respuestas sin votos ni marcadas como aceptadas.  Te recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Muestra el codigo de tu Conexion, es obvio que el error esta ahi. En tu metodo conectar() estas retornando un string en vez de la coneccion en si.  Ademas, en el constructor, no tiene sentido que crees una instancia de la clase Conexion ya que heredas de ella, podrias solo llamar la coneccion con $this->conectar().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dentro de la clase ConexionEn tu metodo conectar() estas retornando un string en vez de la coneccion. tu metodo conectar() deberia verse algo mas o menos asi:

```
    public function conectar()
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseDeDatos','root','password');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
        
       //aqui esta tu error, probablemente estas retornando un string.
      //debes devolver la coneccion, es decir, una instancia de la clase PDO.
        return $conn;
    }
```

Ademas no es necesario crear una instancia de la clase Conexion porque la clase Persona hereda de ella.
Tu constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbConn = $this->conectar();
    }
```